# How to display a toast message in only one activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-toast

In an application I am developing I have some code that attempts to submit information to the internet. If the connection can not be made, I pop up a toast message instructing the user to check the network connection.

```
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check network connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The problem I have is the toast message comes up no matter what the user is looking at! Even if the user is in a different app and my app is running in the background! This is not the desired behavior as I send a notification to the user if network activity fails. I only want the toast message to appear if the user is in the activity that is generating the network activity. Is there a way to do this?

If this is not possible my idea was to just put some kind of visual element in my activity - rather than display a toast message.

Thank You!

Comment: Probably change the context, give it `this` if you're in an activity or `getActivity()` inside a fragment.

Comment: Yeah OP should be able to do a quick check if the application is running/in focus before he displays his toast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dynamic `BroadcastReceiver`. Your background service will broadcast an `Intent` when something happens. All of your app's activities will register a dynamic `BroadcastReceiver` which will listen for these events. When such event occurs it will show a toast. When none of your activities are running nothing will happen.

#### Inside your service

```
public static final ACTION_SOMETHING = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".ACTION_SOMETHING";

public void doSomething() {
    // ...

    // Show toast if app is running. Or let the app react however you please.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_SOMETHING));

    // ...
}
```

Of course you can put additional information in the `Intent` as extras and access them in the `BroadcastReceiver`.

#### Inside your activities

```
private final IntentFilter onSomethingIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(MyService.ACTION_SOMETHING);
private final BroadcastReceiver onSomething = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // This check seems redundant but it's not. Google it.
        if (MyService.ACTION_SOMETHING.equals(intent.getAction()) {
            // Show toast here.
        }
    }
};

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Start listening for events when activity is in foreground.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onSomething, onSomethingIntentFilter);
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Stop listening as soon as activity leaves foreground.
    try {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(onSomething);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {}
}
```

You may want to pull this code to a common activity parent, a `BaseActivity`, so you don't repeat yourself.

This is a common case of Provider-Subscriber pattern. Another implementation would be an [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm! I should have been more clear in my initial question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean class member in order to keep track of activity state changes.

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {

    private boolean mIsResumed = false;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mIsResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mIsResumed = false;
    }

    public boolean isResumed() {
        return mIsResumed;
    }
}
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
if (isResumed()) {
    //show Toast
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple, try adding a boolean flag in Activity and set its value as **true in onResume** & **false in onPause**. Then display the toast if the boolean flag is **true**.

Comment: Again, how does OP reach the flag from a background service?

Comment: Thank You! I will be using these methods in a different portion of my program than this question! Thank you for bringing these to my attention! @sJy

Comment: @EugenPechanec The question was lil bit incomplete. It said it needed to show toast only when the user is in the activity that initiated the network transaction. So my answer also was simple. Anyway your answer was more informative & fixed the real issue.Cheers!!!